# Powershell script get .NET Framework versions from remote PCs

Tags: powershell, dotnet-framework

I have the following script.

```
Get-Content comps.csv | Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, Version, Release
```

My comps.csv content

`Name,Type,Description,
ALYTAUS-PC,Computer,,
AUGUSTE-PC,Computer,,
AUSRA-PC,Computer,,
BIRZU-PC,Computer,,
VYTAUTO-PC1,Computer,,`

I got that message for each object in csv:

`Get-ChildItem : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does n
ot take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:38
+ Get-Content comps.csv | Get-ChildItem <<<<  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (VYTAUTO-PC1,Computer,,:PSObject) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Answer (score 2):

Get-ChildItem waits *path* from pipeline, not a computer name. First thing that you need is get computer object with it's attributes (name, type, description) from CSV file:

```
Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\servers.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Write-Host "Server name: " -NoNewline
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

Next you need to execute commands remotely with Invoke-Command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP'
}
```

Finally:

```
Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\servers.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP'
    }
}
```

To run script block with specified credentials use parameter -Credential in Invoke-Command.

Comment: Read about running remote commands in Windows PowerShell by entering command `Get-Help about_Remote_Requirements`